# I am facing an issue adding a linker flag "-ObjC" to the build phase in Card-io in the iOS SDK

Tags: ios, card.io

I am facing a problem adding a linker flag: `"-ObjC"` to the build phase.

In my project, I have used several third party SDKs, and Facebook as well; when I run my app with the `"-ObjC"` flag it does not run the code, and when I remove it scanning crashes with the message: `Add "-Objc"`. Is there any way to use Card-io without a linker flag???

Answer (score 0):

In your project's `Build Settings` under `TARGETS`, add `-lc++` to `Other Linker Flags`.

You also need to set `armv7+ (including 64-bit)`

[image: Other linker Flags]